# CMAKE only has Win32 option when generating a project for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I created a C++ project using CMAKE.

I want to add 64 and 32 bit builds.

When I run the command `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` and open the resulting `.sln` file, I see there is only the Win32 option.

I can run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` and then there is only an `x64` option.

How do I specify that I want both 64 and 32 bit versions built?

Is this something I can do in my `CmakeLists.txt` file or do I have to specify it with flags on the command line?

Additionally, I see the following targets:
`Debug`
`MinSizeRel` 
`Release`
`RealeaseWithDebugInfo`

How are those ^ configured?

If I only want "debug" and release mode enabled, how do I do that?

Comment: With CMake a project can not support both 32 and 64 bit at the same time. You can only build one or the other. To solve this  I use totally separate build trees with the same shared source (with out of source building). Although these days I rarely build 32 bit.